# Figure is almost empty after PDF export in Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to export an Excel figure to PDF:

[image]

It worked fine for other figures, but for this one I get a pretty disappointing output:

[image]

instead of having:

[image]

What can explain this issue?

Other graphs which I believe contain just as much information can be exported to a PDF without any issues, e.g.:

[image]

Restarting Microsoft Excel didn't help.

I use Microsoft Excel 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Here is the [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37pue4vno4e2qji/stats.xlsx?dl=0) I use.

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.